# Local Coordinates of Symplectic Hypersurface

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, symplectic-geometry

If $H$ is a hypersurface (codimension 1) in a symplectic manifold, show that near any point
of $H$ there are local coordinates in which $H = \{\xi_1 = 0 \}$ and the symplectic
form is $\sum_{i=1}^n
d\xi_i ∧ dx_i$.

I know how to prove a similar result for Lagrangian submanifolds, but it doesn't apply in this case. Any ideas?